# Want to Change heat panel thermostat to wall 2 pole (with off)

Tags: wiring

Supply line enters left panel of Cadet heat panel and I will be removing thermostat on panel and replacing with wall thermostat. Need help deciding type of wire to connect to the L1 L2 and T1 T2 wires from thermostat on wall. One 12-2 wire? Or do I need 2?

Comment: Cadet makes a big line of heaters. The required wire size will depend on the heater size. What size heater? What is the current breaker size?

Comment: 8 ft heater double breaker

Comment: What size is the breaker?

Comment: Has 20 amp breaker

Comment: Model # of thermostat?